# Python: calling external functions within functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, and am having a problem: I want to write a function (`Jacobian`) which takes a function and a point as arguments, and returns the [jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of that function at the given point.

Unsurprisingly, `Jacobian` relies on NumPy and SciPy. When I call `Jacobian` from another script, I get either:

1. An error that says I cannot import a module into a function (when I have an import statement for NumPy/SciPy in `Jacobian`) or
2. Errors that various NumPy/Scipy functions (e.g. `zeros()`) are not defined, (when I omit the import statement to avoid the error mentioned above.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if someone knows of an implementation of `Jacobian`, that would be useful as well. There doesn't seem to be one in SciPy.

Comment: Can you post some of the code giving you a problem? What you're describing should definitely be possible, so it's likely some mundane detail of the code that's causing this.

Comment: how do you import it can you paste code ?

Comment: Here's [one page](http://old.nabble.com/calculating-numerical-jacobian-td20506078.html) that discusses calculating the Jacobian. Keep in mind that because Numpy works numerically (not symbolically), your numerical derivative will not be perfectly accurate in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can import at the module level and then use the imported names from inside any functions.
Or you can import any required names directly inside a function.

There is one situation where you cannot use `import` inside a function: you are not allowed to do `from somemodule import *` because the Python compiler wants to know all of the local variables in the function and with `import *` it cannot tell in advance what names will be imported.

The solution is simple: never use `import *`, always import exactly the names that you want to use.

P.S. It helps if you copy the code that is giving the problem and the **exact** error message you are getting. I'm guessing here that this is your problem but you'll get faster and more accurate answers if you provide the relevant details.

Comment: Note that `from ... import *` is allowed in Python 2.x, so I'm guessing the OP is using 3.x.  Of course, the actual error would make it so we don't have to guess.